# prestashop 1.4.1 ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop

I'm trying to call a function of my new module in ajax but I can't. I receive a "500 Internal Server Error", however my url is good.

my php file (module.php)

```
class test extends Module{

    function ajax_test(){
        #do some stuff
    }
}
```

my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "module.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data : {},
      success: 
         function(data){

         }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 500 error is a generic error code meaning that the script failed. You can enable display_errors in the php.ini file to view what the error is.